# how to search with date range in codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

i try to make a search data in column "tgl_lapor" use date range, but still get error.

this is my model

```
        function all($tgl_lapor,$id_tujuanlapor,$id_kategorilapor,$usergroup) {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('lapor');



        if($tgl_lapor!=""){

             $this->db->where("('tgl_lapor >=' ,$tgl_lapor) AND ('tgl_lapor <=' ,$tgl_lapor)");    

        }
```

this the controller

```
        public function index()
        { 

        $tgl_lapor = $this->input->get('tgl_lapor');
```

and this the view

```
                          <th>
                               <input type="text" class="form-control" name="tgl_lapor" placeholder="From">
                          </th> 

                          <th>
                               <input type="text" class="form-control" name="tgl_lapor" placeholder="To">
                          </th>
```

and i get the error

```
    Error Number: 1241

    Operand should contain 1 column(s)

    SELECT * FROM (`lapor`) WHERE ('tgl_lapor >=' ,2015-01-24) AND ('tgl_lapor <=' ,2015-01-24)

    Filename: D:\xampp\htdocs\zz\system\database\DB_driver.php

    Line Number: 330
```

Answer (score 0):

*Updated on 2015-02-26:*

Hi!

My wild guess is that you need to split the range into two variables.

Controller

```
    public function index() { 
        $tgl_lapor_from = $this->input->get('tgl_lapor_from');
        $tgl_lapor_to = $this->input->get('tgl_lapor_to');
        ...
    }
```

View

```
   <th>
       <input type="text" class="form-control" name="tgl_lapor_from" placeholder="From">
   </th>
   <th>
       <input type="text" class="form-control" name="tgl_lapor_to" placeholder="To">
   </th>
```

Model

```
function all($tgl_lapor_from, $tgl_lapor_to, $id_tujuanlapor, $id_kategorilapor, $usergroup){
 $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('lapor');
    if($tgl_lapor_from!="" && $tgl_lapor_to!=""){
         $query = 'tgl_lapor BETWEEN "$tgl_lapor_from" AND "$tgl_lapor_to"'; 
         $this->db->where($query);    
    }
}
```

...else case, the query will never touch the tgl_lapor column. You're trying to tie two different values after all (since it is a RANGE).

Comment: but i use the tgl_lapor to show data from that column

Comment: You need to read the error message with some care.

SELECT * FROM (`lapor`) WHERE ('tgl_lapor >=' ,2015-01-24) AND ('tgl_lapor <=' ,2015-01-24)

That query is not right, is it? ;)

Comment: yes :D and when i try your answer, the error became : SELECT * FROM (`lapor`) WHERE ('tgl_lapor >=' ,2015-01-24) AND ('tgl_lapor <=' ,2015-02-25)

Comment: Which leads me to believe that you might be searching for another way to compare DATE types in a MySQL query.


`SELECT * FROM (`lapor`) WHERE 'tgl_lapor' BETWEEN "2015-01-25" AND "2015-02-25"`

Comment: yes, you right. i just try to add $tgl_lapor_from and $tgl_lapor_to without delete the $tgl_lapor. and that error displayed

Comment: Try to implement my answer and then you tell me how did it go.

Comment: and still displayed the error SELECT * FROM (`lapor`) WHERE ('tgl_lapor >=' ,2015-01-24) AND ('tgl_lapor <=' ,2015-02-25)

i have been split/change the tgl_lapor became tgl_lapor_from and tgl_lapor_to

Comment: Check again my previous post...

`SELECT * FROM ( lapor ) WHERE tgl_lapor BETWEEN <a> AND <b>`

Comment: this is the error, when i try use between a and b. 
i try tthis in the models          $this->db->where("('tgl_lapor') BETWEEN '$tgl_lapor_from' AND '$tgl_lapor_to')");

and the error  :
Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 3

SELECT * FROM (`lapor`) WHERE ('tgl_lapor') BETWEEN '2015-01-24' AND '2015-02-25')

Comment: Check the model in my answer again, I updated it. Remove parenthesis and aphostrophes. They are being a nuisance.

I tested my method in my own database and it works.